# How to plot an arrow in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot a singular vector in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) using arrow function, but MATLAB keeps giving me the error:

> Undefined function 'arrow' for input arguments of type 'double'

How do I fix this?

Here is the MATLAB code:

```
function Plot_Singular_Vecor()
A=[1 1;2 3];

[U,S,V] = svd(A); % Find singular value decomposition.

figure;
theta = -pi:pi/50:pi;
circle = [cos(theta); sin(theta)]; 
plot(circle(1,:), circle(2,:), 'r'), grid
title('Right Singular Vectors, u1 and u2')
hold on;
arrow([0,0], [V(1,1), V(2,1)])
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the [`arrow`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278) function from MATLAB file exchange, or if you have the function, make sure it's in your PATH.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use the built-in function quiver

```
quiver(0,0,V(1,1),V(2,1))
```

or the annotation function

```
annotation('arrow',[0,0],[V(1,1),V(2,1)])
```

Comment: Explanation: `quiver(X,Y,Vx,Vy)` will draw an arrow from `(X,Y)` to `(X+a*Vx,Y+a*Vy)` where `a` is some automatically-computed factor.